# Defining a case-control study design for the dataset

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am here to ask question related to R programming language.
In "R" i know how to define miodin project which i have done like this

```
library(miodin)
mp <- MiodinProject(
    name = "My Project",
    author = "lee",
    path = ".")
mshow(mp)
```

But i need a little help with defining a case-control study design for the dataset that is in my computer memory which has a name "seq.txt" and not in some online database.So how can i define study design for that dataset?

Answer (score 0):

```
install.packages("readtext")
library(readtext)
```

## Will get you the work direct you are on in R

```
getwd()
```

## Set the work direct to best fit your project, use quotes `" "` and `/` forward slash to path inside `( )` for `setwd()`.

```
setwd("/Users/r/Desktop/Prog/R/")
```

## Put the file in the work direct, make sure using `getwd()`

## Use this and store in a variable

```
df <- readtext("seq.txt")
```

If you want more help forward that post example of the data so we can help you figure it out.
*TIP: Always crate a New project in R--> File --> New Project*

Comment: I want to read the text as a data frame please help me with that.

Comment: if you fallow these steps above, you just have to click on `df` on the global envirionment or View(df)

Comment: I followed the steps mentioned above and i got an error that says  "Error in .External2(C_dataviewer, x, title) : unable to start data viewer
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In View(df) :
  locale not supported by Xlib: some X ops will operate in C locale
2: In View(df) : X cannot set locale modifiers
3: In View(df) :
  unable to create fontset -*-fixed-medium-r-*-*-*-120-*-*-*-*-*-* "

Comment: use sessionInfo() and a print screen. Maybe with that we can solve this for once. This is weird

Comment: this doesn't seem to work can you help me with the data frame error?

Comment: well, you have to use R studio, use sessionInfo() is a built in function... so we need more than that to help you out.

Comment: Can you look into this problem by going on this link? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61758189/arguments-imply-differing-number-of-rows-15-12  please?